# Anonymous new View.OnClickListener() can be replaced with lambda

Tags: java, android, android-studio

What kind of warning is this? Is this big deal? Can anyone explain me what this is?

[image]

Comment: Next time you ask a question please take a screenshot instead of taking a picture from an external camera.

Comment: Plus I would suggest to copy-paste the error message and place it in the title for reference

Comment: @Olympiloutre there is no error message.

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException my bad its in the title already

Comment: @Olympiloutre No, you do not understand: The OP's question doesn't have an error. He/she is asking for a course of action.

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException I perfectly got it, he wants explaination on "Anonymous new View.OnClickListener() can be replaced with lambda" which is a warning message (not an error my bad). I didnt saw it in the title so I suggested to past this message in his/her question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not a big deal. It is just a suggestion that you can convert that piece of code to a lambda.

## Here is an example:

**without lambda expressions it might look like:**

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        doSomething();
    }
});
```

**with lambda expressions It is as simple as:**

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(v -> doSomething(););
```

Comment: what happens if I convert that into code to lambda?

Comment: Nothing. It just puts your code into a more compact form.

Comment: What is a compact form?