# Java: Anonymous new View.OnClickListener() can be replaced with lambda

Tags: java, android

Can anyone help me with this error

> Anonymous new View.OnClickListener() can be replaced with lambda

```
button_copy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
            String scanned_text = textview_data.getText().toString();
            copyToClipBoard(scanned_text);
      }
});
```

Comment: It's your IDE offering 'advice' about how to 'improve' your code. It's not an error. There is nothing actually wrong with the code.

Comment: Does this answer of your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57137935/anonymous-new-view-onclicklistener-can-be-replaced-with-lambda?

Comment: please guide me on how to remove or ignore this issue im unable to build my apk

Comment: This is not an error and should not prevent you from building. If you can't build it is most likely from some other cause. Check the build tab for other errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone help me with this error

As noted in the comments it is NOT an error.  It is *style advice* provided by your IDE (I guess).

You could ignore it, and there are probably IDE-specific settings to selectively turn off this kind of message.  But it is easy to just follow the IDE's suggestion and replace the anonymous class with a lambda; e.g.

```
button_copy.setOnClickListener(
        v -> copyToClipBoard(textview_data.getText().toString());
```

Comment: button_capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CropImage.activity().setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON).start(MainActivity.this);
            }
        });  
       
        please help me reformat this code as well tried my best but the parameters are confusing me alot

Comment: You should be able to work it out.  It is not difficult.  Try harder.  If not, look for a tutorial on Java8+ lambdas.  Or if lambdas are too hard, do one of the other things I suggested: 1) ignore the advice, or 2) look for the setting to turn of the advice.

Comment: ACTUALLY IVE WORKED IT OUT THANK YOU SOO MUCH FOR YOUR GUIDANCE

Comment: Excellent.  Perseverance is a good strategy.